# Pywikibot MediaWiki Query API

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I have a data dump of Wikipedia articles listed only by their pageid, and I am hoping to filter them by namespace. It would be relatively easy to write some python (probably using the requests module) to call the [MediaWiki Query API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query), to query for namespaces 50 at a time using the pageids param.

But, I was going to try to use Pywikibot instead, as the best practices and error handling for querying the API are likely baked into Pywikibot, and less likely to get my IP banned if I make a logical error and over-query the API. (In addition, I am hoping to gain experience with this module for my future bot writing endeavors)

However, I can't really find very good documentation for Pywikibot, and am having trouble finding language in the existing doc about this API. I have also tried various other python packages in hopes to find bindings (is that the correct usage of bindings?) with this API, to no avail.

Comment: a page in pywikibot can not be instantiate through the pageid, so I think you better use the query api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pywikibot does not have much in the way of developer documentation, usually you have to read the source ([data/api.py](https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot-core/blob/master/pywikibot/data/api.py) in this case). [python-mwapi](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwapi) and [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) are some well-maintained, well-documented libraries.

Answer (score -2):

You will find the API documentation [here](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/stable/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28237984)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica This seems to be the official documentation, which is the Answer to this Question. See [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic)